# What is the difference between worker.kill vs process.exit in Node.JS

Tags: node.js

When using Node.js's `cluster` feature, what is the difference between ending a forked process with `process.exit()` and [`worker.kill()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_kill_signal_sigterm), and when should I use each?

My goal here is when the worker finishes its tasks, it should end its process. When the cluster is notified that the worker emits an `exit` event, it forks a new worker.

Comment: `worker.kill()` is something you call from the master process and you call it on the `worker` object that you have access to in the master process to kill one of the worker processes.  `process.exit()` is something you call from inside the worker process if you want to stop it from within the process.

Comment: I can also call `cluster.worker.kill()` though, from within the worker.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to shut the cluster down?  Why are you trying to kill a worker and do you want the worker to be restarted after you kill it?

Comment: That isn't how cluster workers are supposed to be used.  The cluster module rotates jobs to different workers for you.  An idle worker isn't killed and restarted, it's just waiting for the next job to be sent to it by the cluster manager.  Why kill the process?  Why not just send it a message to process the next job?